# Easyhook Send Packet Trouble

Tags: c#, sockets, hook, easyhook

I injected a dll into a game client and hooked send/recv using Easyhook. I can easily monitor the packets that the client send to the server and receive from the server. I want to send my own packets so I made a function like this :

```
public static void SendPacket()
{
   string packet= "dance emotion packet";
   byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(packet);
   IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(byData.Length);
   Marshal.Copy(byData, 0, unmanagedPointer, byData.Length);
   send(socket, unmanagedPointer, byData.Length, 0);
}
```

I think the program sends the packet just fine but I don't receive anything from the server. For example if I send a packet to do a dance emotion, the server doesn't respond. The interesting thing is when I do something in the client (for example open a shop or move or anything that sends a packet to the server) the server responds to the dance packet that I sent before using the SendPacket() function in my injected dll.

So the problem is either my dll can't send the packet or the server doesn't respond. Anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like an EasyHook issue. You're probably missing some specific game protocol nuance that only works after the game itself correctly sends the information the server needs to respond to your injected packet.